Dynamic Layer: valueExpression in ClassBreaksRenderer doesn't return correct value
I am using a FeatureLayer created from a dynamic Layer, where the source is a JoinedLayer. I am joining a MapLayer and a QueryTable. Said FeatureLayer has a ClassBreaksRenderer and as the JoinedLayer creates random table names in the field name, the field name for the renderer has to be calculated dynamically.
As such I am using a valueExpression in Arcade to get the field whose name ends in my desired fieldName (in this case let's pretend it is called debugfield). I am using this code as the valueExpression:
      for(var f in $feature){                   
        var debugIndex = Find("debugfield", f);                    
        if(debugIndex > -1){
          return $feature[f];
        }
      }

I am getting a log that it finds values for each feature, however on some of them it returns 
I've tried logging the values and as such it finds the fields, but the values are then empty strings.

Please clarify the error/issue you're running into further (e.g. share your console logs and a more complete code snippet that includes the FeatureLayer and ClassBreaksRenderer JavaScript/auto-castable JSON in addition to your Arcade expression)
